# Kibana - aliasing fields in visualization

Tags: kibana, kibana-5

I have a Data Table visualization.

[image]
The statuses have there own values,

1 - Net Banking
2 - Cash On delivery
3 - Mobile payment

Is there any way I can alias these values to their meaning in this data table ?

Comment: I think you can do that with script field, navigate to management -> index-pattern, their choose script field. Another approach it simple index another field that contain the payment status text